# Android same views has different size

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, view

I met a strange problem as below. In a RecyclerView, the second avatar and title is bigger than the first one, as the red rect marked.

Any one could give some advice? Thanks.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/vc_character_item_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:paddingHorizontal="@dimen/common_dp_12"
        android:paddingVertical="@dimen/common_dp_12"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/common_dp_16"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/common_dp_12"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_round_solid_r16_neutral_surface"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.yuewen.dreamer.common.ui.widget.RoundImageView
                android:id="@+id/vc_character_item_avatar"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/common_dp_72"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/common_dp_72"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/skin_neutral_surface_medium"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:round_width="@dimen/common_dp_36" />

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/vc_character_item_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="@dimen/common_dp_14"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:includeFontPadding="false"
                android:drawablePadding="@dimen/common_dp_4"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/common_dp_4"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/vc_character_item_avatar"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                tools:text="家人在册"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/common_dp_8"
                android:textColor="@color/neutral_content" />

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/vc_create_by_self_tv"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/common_dp_6"
                android:background="@drawable/shape_round_solid_r4_neutral_surface_medium"
                android:paddingHorizontal="4dp"
                android:paddingVertical="2dp"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:textSize="10dp"
                android:text="我创建的"
                android:visibility="gone"
                tools:visibility="visible"
                android:textColor="@color/neutral_content_medium_p48"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/vc_character_item_name"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/vc_character_item_name"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/vc_character_item_name" />

        <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/vc_character_item_info_group"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/vc_character_item_avatar"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/vc_character_item_name"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/common_dp_8"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/common_dp_4"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/vc_character_item_id_tag"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/common_dp_12"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    tools:text="9999人入梦 · 共23个梦境 "
                    android:textColor="@color/neutral_content_medium_p48" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/vc_character_tag_group"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/common_dp_4"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/common_dp_8"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/vc_character_item_avatar"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/vc_character_item_info_group"
                android:orientation="horizontal" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is the layout xml file, and is used for RecyclerView itemView .And i never modify avatar size and text size in java code. But as the image shows , item's avatar and title's text size not consistence.

Comment: Can you share the code for your recyclerview items?

Comment: We need the layout of the recycler item

Comment: Could the images themselves be of different size and your layout adapts to it?

Comment: I have paste the xml file above , i never modified the avatar size or TextView's text size in code. @tomerpacific

Comment: I solved this problem. The reason is in somewhere modified the activity resource density and applicion resource density.